# i have 3 'wish' links in my page.so,i want to get the total count of such links and perform click operation on them one by one

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

```
List<WebElement> bdaywish = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@data-original-title='Send a Birthday Wish']"));

       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

       System.out.println("total birthday wishes :"+bdaywish.size());

       for (int i=0;i<bdaywish.size();i++) {

           bdaywish.get(i).click();
           System.out.println("birthday Wish "+i);
          }
```

I have 3 `wish` links in my page. So, I want to get the total count of such links and perform click operation on them one by one.

But, while trying to do so using above script, only first element with linktext `wish` is clicked. This line is executed `bdaywish.get(i).click();`
once only. The next line is not executed. The `bdaywish.size()` is getting `3`.

But, only one click operation is performed.
What is going wrong? Thanks.

HTML code:

Wish
    
 
  Wish
 
     Tomorrow: All day

Comment: What happens, when you click that link? If the browser is navigating away from the site, it cannot click again for the link is no longer there. In that case you actually should have seen a `StaleElementException` in the second iteration.

Comment: after clicking on link,the page gets reloaded.No exception is coming.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_